# How to convert byte array to image and display in datagrid?

Tags: c#

I have made a sql database using sql server. This database include images. When I display this database in a datagrid, byte[]array displays in the image column. How do I convert from a byte array back to an image and then display that image in the datagrid? Any help or tutorials are appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
 Image image= Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look a this tutorial:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Images-Database.aspx