# display images in repeater control from linq datasource

Tags: asp.net, mysql, linq, repeater

I have a `linq datasource` to a repeater control in asp.net.
I want to display images stored in the database tables.
i have a category table and product table among other tables, when i used this code

```
<% Eval("CategoryImage")%> .
```

It displays `System.byte[]` in the browser and when I used asp image control with `Eval();` it give me a usual broken image icon.

could somebody suggest me a way to insert image directly from the `mysql database` itself via `linq datasource..` 
And how could I format html tags in stack overflow and asp tags too.. 
Thanks in advance help appreciated...

Comment: you need to convert the byte array to an image

Comment: A way I know is to create `http-handler` and give image source of that handler.

Comment: @Shekhar I m getting this error: that ByteArrayToImage(Byte[]) has some invalid Arguments on <%#byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage")) %> please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
 {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
 }
```

to convert the byte array to image.

And if you have `byte array` in `Eval("CategoryImage")` then you can call this function from `Eval` also.
As

```
<%# byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage"))%>
```

Not tested but it should work.

### Edit 1

Here is a good link
[argumentException was unhandled error when converting byte of array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106179/argumentexception-was-unhandled-error-when-converting-byte-of-array-to-image)

[How to convert byte array to image and display in datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186354/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-datagrid)

Comment: @ub1k dude do you have a train to catch.. i will accept it but let me work on it.

Comment: @Shekhar i am not getting an byte array but just System.Byte[] as output in the browser on using <% Eval("CategoryImage")%>.. could you help me with this..

Comment: Dude from you're answer it's obvious you don't know what you're talking about :(   Byte[] is a Byte array...

Comment: @ub1k please do you know any suggestion to the question then please let me know ..or don't take my I.Q test.. i know i m not a great scholar as you are..

Comment: it's just the answer is provided by Shekhar!

Comment: yeah but it is giving me an error : that ByteArrayToImage(Byte[]) has some invalid Arguments on <%#byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage")) %>