# Binding Byte() to a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a collection which has  items consisting of Id as Integer,Name as String and a IconImage as Byte().

I want to display Name and the image in a gridview but not sure how to bind IconImage to gridview?

```
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:label id="LabelName" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:label>
</itemtemplate>

<!-- Bind and Display the image here-->
```

Please help me with some sample code..
Thanks

Comment: I found another nice article on this topic: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/445876/Auto-bind-byte-to-asp-Image)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
 {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
 }
```

to convert the byte array to image.

And if you have `byte array` in `Eval("CategoryImage")` then you can call this function from `Eval` also.
As

```
<%# byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage"))%>
```

Not tested but it should work.

### Edit 1

Here is a good link
[argumentException was unhandled error when converting byte of array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106179/argumentexception-was-unhandled-error-when-converting-byte-of-array-to-image)

[How to convert byte array to image and display in datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186354/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-datagrid)

Comment: I tried `<ItemTemplate>
                <img id="displayIcon" src="<%# ByteArrayToImage(Eval("IconImage"))%>"
                    width="125px" height="125px" title="<%# Eval("Description") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>`
   but can't see any images,only cross(x) in the columns, any ideas?

Comment: Do the `IconImage` is a byte array?

Comment: yes it is a byte array, maybe I'm using the wrong control to bind it to, I'm not sure if src can directly display an image, maybe it's expecting a full path to a file